# Parsing JSON with nested documents

Tags: c#, json.net

I have large class for json converting.

```
Tasks task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tasks>(JObject.Parse(x)["result"]["task"].ToString());
```

Here's the [sample json](https://pastebin.com/d7ALbpka)

I have a scenario where the json document has nested documents. Sometimes there could be a nested document, sometimes not. How do i parse this kind of json document?

Comment: how's the JSON looks?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d7ALbpka

Comment: The idea is very simple. Create a few model classes and sub-classes. Then parse-and-cast the json to those objects(aka models). Do a null check if you want, otherwise if null, the object/properties will be null by default

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ud5C06BR

Comment: I tried to make this class but it doesnt work

Comment: The structure of the class makes no sense.

Comment: give examples for task having string, bool & object. dont copy entire json. create a simple json files to make us understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

Based on your JSON string in your question, I have prepared a sample working class structure with the de-serialization for the string into your associated `Model`. As you mentioned in your comments that `uFCrmTask` can be a array, I have implemented your case with a custom converter that will handle this case.

Working Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VrGNo9

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json=@"{'result':{'task':{'id':'1163','parentId':null,'title':'qwe','description':'','mark':null,'priority':'1','status':'2','multitask':'N','notViewed':'N','replicate':'N','groupId':'0','stageId':'0','createdBy':'1','createdDate':'2020-01-08T10:43:45+03:00','responsibleId':'1','changedBy':'1','changedDate':'2020-01-08T10:43:45+03:00','statusChangedBy':'1','statusChangedDate':'2020-01-08T10:43:45+03:00','closedBy':null,'closedDate':null,'dateStart':null,'deadline':null,'startDatePlan':null,'endDatePlan':null,'guid':'{4b4a2708-36b4-4e81-b422-2c07d28de266}','xmlId':null,'commentsCount':null,'allowChangeDeadline':'Y','taskControl':'N','addInReport':'N','forkedByTemplateId':null,'timeEstimate':'0','timeSpentInLogs':null,'matchWorkTime':'N','forumTopicId':null,'forumId':null,'siteId':'s1','subordinate':'N','favorite':'N','exchangeModified':null,'exchangeId':null,'outlookVersion':'1','viewedDate':'2020-01-08T10:43:46+03:00','sorting':'21504.2500000','durationPlan':null,'durationFact':null,'durationType':'days','descriptionInBbcode':'Y','ufCrmTask':false,'ufTaskWebdavFiles':[],'ufMailMessage':null,'auditors':[],'accomplices':[],'checklist':[],'group':[],'creator':{'id':'1','name':'??????? ????','link':'/company/personal/user/1/','icon':'/bitrix/images/tasks/default_avatar.png'},'responsible':{'id':'1','name':'??????? ????','link':'/company/personal/user/1/','icon':'/bitrix/images/tasks/default_avatar.png'},'action':{'accept':false,'decline':false,'complete':true,'approve':false,'disapprove':false,'start':true,'pause':false,'delegate':true,'remove':true,'edit':true,'defer':true,'renew':false,'create':false,'changeDeadline':true,'checklistAddItems':true,'addFavorite':true,'deleteFavorite':false,'edit.originator':true,'checklist.reorder':true,'elapsedtime.add':true,'dayplan.timer.toggle':false,'edit.plan':true,'checklist.add':true,'favorite.add':true,'favorite.delete':false}}},'time':{'start':1578473027.682132,'finish':1578473027.950497,'duration':0.26836490631103516,'processing':0.018194198608398438,'date_start':'2020-01-08T11:43:47+03:00','date_finish':'2020-01-08T11:43:47+03:00'}}";
        var Sresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.result.task.changedBy);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.result.task.descriptionInBbcode);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.result.task.multitask);

    }
}

public class Creator
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Responsible
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public bool accept { get; set; }
    public bool decline { get; set; }
    public bool complete { get; set; }
    public bool approve { get; set; }
    public bool disapprove { get; set; }
    public bool start { get; set; }
    public bool pause { get; set; }
    public bool @delegate { get; set; }
    public bool remove { get; set; }
    public bool edit { get; set; }
    public bool defer { get; set; }
    public bool renew { get; set; }
    public bool create { get; set; }
    public bool changeDeadline { get; set; }
    public bool checklistAddItems { get; set; }
    public bool addFavorite { get; set; }
    public bool deleteFavorite { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("edit.originator")]
    public bool editoriginator { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("checklist.reorder")]
    public bool checklistreorder { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("elapsedtime.add")]
    public bool elapsedtimeadd { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dayplan.timer.toggle")]
    public bool dayplantimertoggle { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("edit.plan")]
    public bool editplan { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("checklist.add")]
    public bool checklistadd { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("favorite.add")]
    public bool favoriteadd { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("favorite.delete")]
    public bool favoritedelete { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object parentId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public object mark { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string multitask { get; set; }
    public string notViewed { get; set; }
    public string replicate { get; set; }
    public string groupId { get; set; }
    public string stageId { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string responsibleId { get; set; }
    public string changedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime changedDate { get; set; }
    public string statusChangedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime statusChangedDate { get; set; }
    public object closedBy { get; set; }
    public object closedDate { get; set; }
    public object dateStart { get; set; }
    public object deadline { get; set; }
    public object startDatePlan { get; set; }
    public object endDatePlan { get; set; }
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public object xmlId { get; set; }
    public object commentsCount { get; set; }
    public string allowChangeDeadline { get; set; }
    public string taskControl { get; set; }
    public string addInReport { get; set; }
    public object forkedByTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string timeEstimate { get; set; }
    public object timeSpentInLogs { get; set; }
    public string matchWorkTime { get; set; }
    public object forumTopicId { get; set; }
    public object forumId { get; set; }
    public string siteId { get; set; }
    public string subordinate { get; set; }
    public string favorite { get; set; }
    public object exchangeModified { get; set; }
    public object exchangeId { get; set; }
    public string outlookVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime viewedDate { get; set; }
    public string sorting { get; set; }
    public object durationPlan { get; set; }
    public object durationFact { get; set; }
    public string durationType { get; set; }
    public string descriptionInBbcode { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<bool>))]
    public List<bool> ufCrmTask { get; set; }
    public List<object> ufTaskWebdavFiles { get; set; }
    public object ufMailMessage { get; set; }
    public List<object> auditors { get; set; }
    public List<object> accomplices { get; set; }
    public List<object> checklist { get; set; }
    public List<object> group { get; set; }
    public Creator creator { get; set; }
    public Responsible responsible { get; set; }
    public Action action { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Task task { get; set; }
}

public class Time
{
    public double start { get; set; }
    public double finish { get; set; }
    public double duration { get; set; }
    public double processing { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_start { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_finish { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public Time time { get; set; }
}

//Custom converter to handle single type or array type
class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: But it will not work because uFCrmTask can be array!